# Protecting source code from theft from the past developer who leave the company

Tags: security, authentication

Is there any way to protect my code so that if a developer leaves my company they are unable to access files in my project?

save code specially from where the project is downloaded locally, cached, and available for offline use or saved in mail by making a zip of a code. Ideally the code would not be open other then the work station.

Is this possible by any way?

Comment: No, and trying to cripple their computer is almost certainly going to result in them leaving your awful company a lot faster.

Comment: I am also a developer I ask this question to learn something new So Please dont consider me as a mean BOSS who dont trust theire developer.
I found no reason to vote negative for this question.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but that's a difficult question to answer.

As a side effect, programmers normally are able to copy their own code elsewhere (i can do with almost all the code I have written, for sure ---that's probably more than 10 million lines of code).  They have it on their minds.

But, having programmers access only the code they are going to develop is a good countermeasure from stealing all the code.  You have to arrange for compiling only and doing the linking without access to all the code.  You have to distribute all the binaries (object code) to all the development team, and don't allow them to share it (a difficult thing if you allow them to have coffe together)

I find that measure a difficult to apply also, if you untrust your developers, they will untrust you and make unclear, obfuscated code.  This leads to bad, unmaintainable code.

You can use accounts for your developers and change passwords once they are fired.  What else do you mean?

Why you untrust *all your development team* Just for a few ones? Just fire them out and contract sane ones.

How many developers have you working with you? Are they well paid? (this is a good countermeasure to software thief, mainly the cheapest and most productive) are they properly contracted? (you have the rights and the property of that code, right?)  Are you ready to pay for a system that hides the source code of other teams to your developers?

Comment: A comment for the downvote would be a good thing to know why somebody can disagree with my answer.